# How to write a pipe (|) in batch file from another batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make `.bat` script from another `.bat` script where I have to insert a command which has pipe `|` in it. When I executed the main script I got an error. I tried to figure it out by putting `"|"` or making whole command in between quotes, `"command"`.

Comment: The question has been asked and answered multiple times before with that and other poisonous characters. As you're not new to this site, you should be aware of how to use the search facility. Anyhow, if you take a look at [Microsofts' echo command page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo), and read the last bulleted remark, you should get your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the character `|` using caret `^`
As an example, here is a `batch-file` called `dummy.cmd` which needs to create another batch file called `ping_script.cmd`

```
@(echo ping localhost ^| findstr /i "reply")>ping_script.cmd
```

You can also do numerous outputs to the file. Here is the same script, but it also adds a line to echo `test` newline `script`. Here you will see that the special character is also being escape, else the first batch file will see it as an operator for itself. Below that, it can still do whatever is needed in the first script, like testing if `ping_script.cmd` exists.

```
@(echo ping localhost ^| findstr /i "reply"
echo echo Test ^& echo Script
)>ping_script.cmd
if exist ping_script.cmd echo Success
```

Note, not all special characters can be escaped using caret. This [link at Rob van Der Woude](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) shows a decent table.